# attribute-directive used with ng-attr or ng-class

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-directive

### preface

I've seen many questions regarding using ng-attr and directives however I have yet to see this specific case being implemented.

### code & plunkr

http://bit.ly/1s6gWkD

### use case

I'm trying to dynamically add a loading overlay into target DOM elements via an attribute directive.  The idea is that by virtue of the target DOM element possessing the attribute directive, the DOM will have the overlay appended to its children.

I've approached this from various angles with no luck.  Because this is going to be used in many places where we might want to block certain UIs but not fully block the app with a modal, I am hoping to keep our templates clean and attach this dynamically.

### questions

- is this possible (assuming there IS a directive life-cycle event to tackle this), BTW this is what I would call the dynamic approach
- if not possible, I did try a few less-than-ideal 'static' approaches using this such as with no luck

  - ng-class="{loadOverlay: hasOverlay}"
  - ng-attr-load-overlay="hasOverlay"

### observations

I do realize that there may be an issue with this approach as once the attribute is removed, there may not be a life-cycle event in the directive to know that it is ordered to remove itself.  I don't know enough about directives to know if this is the case.

### ideally what I'm looking for

#### target DOM element w/o overlay

[image]
[image]

#### target DOM element w/ overlay

[image]
[image]

Comment: The link in the question no longer exists but the solution still does http://plnkr.co/edit/rwiHea?p=preview

Comment: yeah there were some issues w/ plnkr a while back that forced some indiscriminate house cleaning of my account.  I must have inadvertently killed the link.  I'll try to rectify ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### settling for the static approach

After giving this some thought I think having a more versatile directive combined with the 'static' approach is the best.

### plunkr solution

http://bit.ly/1toMCV9

#### snips

```
.directive('loadOverlay', function() {

return {

  restrict: 'EA',

  scope: true,

  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    var id = 'nx-load-overlay-' + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);

    function toggleOverlay(show) {
      if (show === true) {
        var d = '<div id="' + id + '" class="nx-load-overlay"><div class="nx-load-overlay-spinner"><span class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x"></span><br/><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:larger;">loading</span></div></div>';
        element.append(d)
      } else {
        $('#' + id).remove()
      }
    }

    if (attrs.loadOverlay)
      scope.$watch(attrs.loadOverlay, toggleOverlay);

    else
      toggleOverlay(true)
  }
}
})
```